# Creating PDF reports in Django backend or frontend?

Tags: django, pdf-generation

I'm currently trying to create reports and was wondering what the best practices around generating PDF reports are.

Should I create them in the backend (using elasticsearch for querying and aggregating the data) or rather send the data to the frontend and generate them there?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-pdf/)? You can user reprtlab and  WeasyPrint or latex for more professional use-cases; but all of them do that in the back-end. I strongly suggest latex if you are trying to make a report or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue here, it seems to me that your PDF generation is part of your business flow: it must respect a few standards/rules and include business data.

This is something you want to have in your backend (backends tend to have a longer life expectancy than frontends)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer back end production because:

1. you have more options for libraries etc.  Browser libs are getting better but not comparable yet.  For example your server could use reach out to a public microservice and you don't need to worry about your api keys being visible on the client.
2. you have access to data you might not want (fully) exposed to the client
3. you have better security on the back-end most likely.
4. you can create and store then deliver the document (if you might need to retrieve the same document later)
5. your implementation is private and you can change it without client's caring

I hope that helps.